# How can I adapt the erase-remove idiom to work with vector tuples?

Tags: c++, erase-remove-idiom

I have a vector of tuples with members j, k, and l. I am trying to adapt the erase-remove idiom such that I can remove an entire tuple if the value of the .k member meets a certain condition.

I tried using the standard .erase(removeif()) methodology where the predicate referenced the tuple member position, but was told that the class of vector in question has no member "k".

```
vec_list_iter_exp_out.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        vec_list_iter_exp_out.begin(),
        vec_list_iter_exp_out.end(), 
        vec_list_iter_exp_out.k < 33), vec_list_iter_exp_out.end());
```

I would expect that if vec_list_iter_exp_out consisted of the following, hypothetical values:

```
vec_list_iter_exp_out[0] = 5, 22, 9
vec_list_iter_exp_out[1] = 12, 31, 54
vec_list_iter_exp_out[2] = 17, 42, 0
vec_list_iter_exp_out[3] = 253, 3, 5
vec_list_iter_exp_out[4] = 65, 110, 24
```

That the entirety of vec_list_iter_exp_out[2] and vec_list_iter_exp_out [4] would be removed and vec_list_iter_exp_out would then consist of the following:

```
vec_list_iter_exp_out[0] = 5, 22, 9
vec_list_iter_exp_out[1] = 12, 31, 54
vec_list_iter_exp_out[2] = 253, 3, 5
```

Instead I get the aforementioned compile error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: definition of the vector in question, as requested.

```
struct TriStore
{
    double j,k,l;
};

std::vector<TriStore> vec_list_iter_exp_out;
```

and snippet for insertion (obviously references other functions and what-have-you, but that would take up far too much space)

```
    for(int z = 1; z <= iters; z++)
    {
        vec_iters.push_back(vec_list_iter_exp_out.size());
        for(int i = vec_iters[z-1]; i < vec_iters[z]; i++)
        {
            if(vec_list_iter_exp_out[i].k < kk)
            {
                triangle_list(vec_list_iter_exp_out[i].j,vec_list_iter_exp_out[i].k,vec_list_iter_exp_out[i].l);
                vec_list_iter_exp_out.insert(vec_list_iter_exp_out.end(),vec_tri_list.begin(),vec_tri_list.end());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `vec_list_iter_exp_out`, and also the code for insertion into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Third argument of [`remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) needs to be a unary predicate. Instead you are passing an expression.

Instead of `vec_list_iter_exp_out.k < 33` try something like `[](const TriStore &x){return x.k < 33;}`

> What if I want to decide this `33` at runtime

From [this comment by Nishant Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052671/how-can-i-adapt-the-erase-remove-idiom-to-work-with-vector-tuples/56052704#comment98747865_56052704): Please use

> ```
> [&value](const TriStore& x) {return x.k < value;}  // Capture by reference
> [value](const TriStore& x) {return x.k < value;}  // Capture by value
> ```

<sup>p.s. Instead of `TriStore` why don't you use `tuple<double, double, double>`?</sup>

Comment: This worked! I can't yet mark the question as answered, but I will as soon as the timer runs out. Also, I'm too new to display an upvote, but I did and your answer was excellent. Thank you!

Comment: I am happy just by knowing that it helped you. I am sure you would love to read about `std::tuple` and lambdas in C++.

Comment: Gyapti, if I wanted to make "33" variable and instead something that was passed into the initial function that this is nested within, how would I go about doing that? I tried to simply use the existing variable name and got this message: "an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list"

Comment: @JudsonClark you need to capture the variable by reference or value like `[&value](const TriStore& x) {return x.k < value;}` where `value` the variable you want capture. Note that I am capturing it by reference, if you want to capture it by value, use `[value](const TriStore& x) {return x.k < value;}`

Comment: Thanks @NishantSingh. I am late to this comment, would add it to the answer.

Comment: So is this the correct implementation?  ```vec_list_iter_exp_out.erase(std::remove_if(vec_list_iter_exp_out.begin(),vec_list_iter_exp_out.end(), [&kk](const TriStore &x){return x.k < kk;}),vec_list_iter_exp_out.end());``` For what it is worth, kk is of type double.